# How to get new records appended (with suppressevents) to tree node in ExtJS4

Tags: extjs, extjs4, appendchild, treegrid

I use ExtJS4 Ext.tree.Panel.

I have to append node to my tree grid, so I used NodeInterface.appendChild(). But, the method works very very slow. Probably, because my tree grid has many columns and renderers.

So, I used suppressevents option. And the method works fast. But, I have another problem. TreeStore.getNewRecords() don't work. I can't find the records appended to Node in TreeStore.

1) Handler method codes of [Append] button

```
var selectedNode = selectionModel.getLastSelected();
for (var i = 0 ; i < len ; i++) {
    selectedNode.appendChild({
        name: 'test name',
        number: i,
        leaf: true
    }, true);       // --> set suppressevents true
}
```

2) Handler method codes of [Save] button

```
var treeStore = treeGrid.getStore();
var records = treeStore.getNewRecords();     // --> records.length == 0
```

How to get new records appended (with suppressevents) to tree node in ExtJS4 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one method. But, I think it's not best.

1) Use the method **"Ext.data.Tree.registerNode()"**

```
var treeStore = treeGrid.getStore();
var selectedNode = selectionModel.getLastSelected();
for (var i = 0 ; i < len ; i++) {
    selectedNode.appendChild({
        name: 'test name',
        number: i,
        leaf: true
    }, true);       // --> set suppressevents true

    // --> Ext.data.Tree in TreeStore has node hash!
    treeStore.tree.registerNode(newNode, false);
}
```